# Reaching limitations creating a gallery of plots

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, figure, subplot

In a script I'm using, the code generates a figure where a number of subplots are generated. Usually it creates a rectangular grid of plots,  but for it's current use, the horizontal parameter only has 1 value, and the vertical parameter has considerably more values than it has had previously. This is causing my program to crash while running, because (presumably) the vertical dimension is too large. The code that's causing the issue is:

```
#can't get past the first line here
self.fig1 = plt.figure('Title',figsize=(4.6*numXparams,2.3*numYparams))
self.gs = gridspec.GridSpec(numYparams,numXparams)
self.gs.update(left=0.03, right=0.97, top=0.9, bottom=0.1, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)
```

and then later in a nested for loop running over both params:

```
ax = plt.subplot(self.gs[par0, par1])
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
X Error of failed request: badAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
Major opcode of failed request: 53 (X_CreatePixmap)
Serial number of failed request: 295
Current serial number in output stream: 296
```

My vertical parameter currently has 251 values in it, so I can see how `251*2.3` inches could lead to trouble. I added in the 2.3*numYparams because the plots were overlapping, but I don't know how to create the figure any smaller without changing how the plots are arranged in the figure. It is important for these plots to stay in a vertically oriented column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code. Fixing them allowed me to generate the figure you are asking for.

```
# I needed the figsize keyword here
self.fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4.6*numXparams,2.3*numYparams))

# You had x and y switched around here
self.gs = gridspec.GridSpec(numYparams,numXparams)
self.gs.update(left=0.03, right=0.97, top=0.9, bottom=0.1, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)

# I ran this loop
for i in range(numYparams):
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(gs[i, 0]) # note the y coord in the gridspec comes first
    ax.text(0.5,0.5,i) # just an identifier

fig1.savefig('column.png',dpi=50) # had to drop the dpi, because you can't have a png that tall!
```

and this is the top and bottom of the output figure:

[image] [image]

Admittedly, there was a lot of space above the first and below the last subplot, but you can fix that by playing with the figure dimensions or `gs.update`

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to try this out. I apologize for the gridspec mix-up - I changed the variable names to make it clearer what was going on, but accidentally put them in the wrong spots. Even when I added the figsize keyword in, I still can't get past the figure creation line.. Any clue what's going on there?

Comment: was able to take care of the problem by specifying the dpi in both the figure creation and saving process. Thanks for the help!